# Function gets executed multiple times

Tags: node.js, singleton, export, require

Inside mining.js I have module.exports like this:

```
module.exports = function(io, socket, player) {
    ...
    function generateOre() {
        player.iron +=1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Inside mining.js I have other functions and variables I need to access from other files. In woodcutting.js I require the mining.js file like this:

```
let mining = require('./mining')(io, socket, player);
```

In other file socket.js I also require both mining and woodcutting

```
let mining = require(./mining)(io, socket, player);
let woodcutting = require(./woodcutting)(io, socket, player);
```

Now when my other function calls generateOre() inside mining.js, the function runs two times. I only want to access certain function and variables from mining.js. How can this be done without running two instances of mining.js?
Or is there a problem when I am requiring mining in two different places?

EDIT:

generateOre() is being called in this function:

```
    socket.on('increase resource', function () {
        clearIntervals();
        generatingIron = setInterval( function() { generateOre() }, BASE.ironRequiredTime * calculateMiningPower());
    }
```

In woodcutting.js I want to be able to call clearIntervals() to clear all mining intervals.

Comment: Post the code where `generateOre()` is called

Comment: @Daniel I edited the code to my original post